# relationship between ingestion latency and ingestion_time()

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Let's say I run the following query precisely at datetime(2021-11-02 05:05:00)

```
MyTable | where ingestion_time() between (datetime(2021-11-02 05:00:00)..5m) | ..
```

Is it guaranteed that all the rows with their ingestion_time() falling within this time window are already available as part of the table? Experimentally I found that roughly up to 10 mins after any given time the data for that latest 5 min time window still keeps flowing. So in this example lets say that even at datetime(2021-11-02 05:10:00) , new rows are still getting populated to the table with ingestion_time() value falling between datetime(2021-11-02 05:00:00) and datetime(2021-11-02 05:05:00). Is it expected ( I guess some basic ingestion latency could be the reason ) ? And if it's expected , should we be setting some delay , say 10-15 min , in our automation to run this query for time range which was 10-15 min old?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such guarantee. If you are looking for a way to perform exactly-once processing of all data, with no data loss guarantees, you should be using [database cursors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/databasecursor).

Comment: Ok, but in practice , provided that we set 15-20 min delay from a given point in time , querying on the basis of ingestion_time() should account for all the data right? I am looking for a way to pull data out of table at fixed interval (e.g. every 5 min) so not sure if cursor is what I can use -- but I can very much set processing delay of 15-20 mins and I noticed that when done like this , number of records remain constant

Comment: the reason database cursors  can't be used in this situation is that these 5 min processing runs are independent and their executions may overlap. So I think the solution in my case is to add sufficient (20 min or more) delay to ensure that data remains constant

Comment: The minimal latency you need to add to guarantee no data loss in this case is 1h. This is because 1h is currently the max timeout for any command. An example of when you might reach 1h delay is if you have a very long chain of update policies - the `ingestion_time()` of first extents in the chain will be assigned first but these extents will only be committed (and available for query) when all update policies have ended (commit time). Since the max timeout for the ingest command is 1h, then after 1h you can be sure that extents with old ingestion_time() will not be committed.